# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, netbeans-8

If i want to map my source address only i.e. @RequestMapping(value="/"), then apache tomcat gives following error:
**org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/application-name/]**

Any other mapping works totally fine.

Comment: Where is your mvc config file? can you show us the config file also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Make sure that you annotated your class containing handler method (the one annotated with @RequestMapping) with @Controller

2) If you don't use spring boot, you may need this annotation: @ComponentScan(/**path to package with components**/) in your configuration class.
This will tell where to look for spring components (controllers are one type of them)

It would be great if you show us your configuration and controller files.